# if statments with "AND , OR"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

please i need help on this code: it compares different values in different column at the same row level and executes the "then statement". But the code i wrote doesn't real function as i expected.

```
Sub Z_status()

Dim wsO As Worksheet
Set wsO = Sheets("Sending List")

Dim i As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

With wsO

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    'Lastrow_2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    'Lastrow_3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    'Lastrow_4 = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
    'For j = Lastrow_2 To 2 Step -1
    'For k = Lastrow_3 To 2 Step -1
    'For l = Lastrow_3 To 2 Step -1

    Cells(1, 7).Value = "Expected state"

    If (Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTS" Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTO") And (Cells(i, 6).Value = "1/1/1900" Or Cells(i, 6).Value > Date) And (Cells(i, 3).Value = 0) And (Cells(i, 8).Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z1"
    ElseIf (Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTS" Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTO") And (Cells(i, 6).Value = "1/1/1900" Or Cells(i, 6).Value > Date) And (Cells(i, 3).Value = 0) And (Cells(i, 8).Value > 0 Or Cells(i, 8).Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z3"
    ElseIf (Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTS" Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTO") And (Cells(i, 6).Value = "1/1/1900" Or Cells(i, 6).Value > Date) And (Cells(i, 3).Value > 0) And (Cells(i, 8).Value > 0 Or Cells(i, 8).Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z5"
    ElseIf (Cells(i, 5).Value = "Obsolete") And (Cells(i, 6).Value < Date) And (Cells(i, 3).Value > 0) And (Cells(i, 8).Value > 0 Or Cells(i, 8).Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z7"
    ElseIf (Cells(i, 5).Value = "Obsolete") And (Cells(i, 6).Value < Date) And (Cells(i, 3).Value = 0) And (Cells(i, 8).Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z9"
    End If

    Next i
   ' Next j
   ' Next k
   ' Next l

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't function as expected - please elaborate. If those cells are all on `wsO` you need a dot in front of them to tie them to the `With` line. As is stands they apply to the active sheet.

Comment: What do you intend to do? We can't help you if you don't tell us what your code is inteded to do and why. Also, lookup for vba rubberduck to help you indent your code correctly.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear.  if the row i of column 3,5,6,8 are true( contains certain values) then output in z1,z3,z5,z7 or z9(depending on which statemnt is true)  in row i of column z. hope im clear now.

Comment: As an extra comment - you use `With ws0` but then don't utilise that going forward. Your `Cells(1, x).Value` should be `.Cells(1, x).Value` - i.e. preceded with a period.

Answer (score 0):

1   Your conditions for Z3 and z5 are identical

2   You can write

```
(Cells(i, 8).Value > 0 Or Cells(i, 8).Value = 0)  

as (Cells(i, 8).Value >= 0 )
```

Your ifs can be written more clearly as

```
If (Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTS" Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "MTO") And (Cells(i, 6).Value = "1/1/1900" Or Cells(i, 6).Value > Date) Then
     If (Cells(i, 8).Value = 0) Then
         Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z1"
     Else
         If (Cells(i, 8).Value > 0) Then
            Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z5"
         End If
    End If
Else
    If (Cells(i, 5).Value = "Obsolete") Then
        If (Cells(i, 6).Value < Date) And (Cells(i, 8).Value >= 0) Then
            If (Cells(i, 3).Value > 0) Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z7"
            Else
                If (Cells(i, 3).Value = 0) Then
                    Cells(i, 7).Value = "Z9"
                Else
                     'This case is undefined
                End If
            End If

        Else
            'This case is undefined
        End If

    Else

       'this case is undefined

    End If
End If
```

Hopefully you can work out the errors more easily in this form

Comment: thanks for the code. actually z3 and z5 are different. in case (Cells(i, 3).Value = 0) and in the other (Cells(i, 3).Value >0)  :)